# EXT JS6 calling Store recursively

Tags: javascript, recursion, synchronization, extjs6-classic

Is it possible to call Store reload recursively:

```
    fetchData: function (sDate, priorDay) {
    store = Ext.getStore('OutOfBalanceList');
    store.reload({
        params: {
            startDate: searchForm.startDate,
            endDate: searchForm.endDate,
            cusip: searchForm.cusip,
            account: searchForm.account
        },
        callback: function (records, options, success) {
            if (records.length == 0) {
                var pdate = priorDay;
                priorDay.setDate(pdate.getDate() - 1);
                sDate.setValue(priorDay);
                searchForm.startDate = Ext.Date.format(sDate.value, 'm/d/Y');
                fetchData(sDate, priorDay);
            }
        }
    });
```

Since the Sync feature seems to be missing, in the Store construct, perhaps that I could obtain the same thing with a recursive call.

If so, could anyone help me to construct the call properly.  I get the error: "***Uncaught ReferenceError:  fetchData is not defined***".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

where did you declare the function fetchData ?

It seems according to the structure that the function fetchData is declared in an object:

```
var plop = {
...
   fetchData: function() {
   ...
   }
}
```

If this is the case, you need to call your function in the scope of of the declared function
    var plop= {
       fetchData: function(...) {
          ...
          plop.fetchData(...)
       }
    }

In your case, I suggest to create a singleton class or something like that which will contain your method fetchData.

Hope it helps, if haven't already solve your problem.